# R code (Rstats) calculating unemployment rate based off columns in long form data

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

I am trying to calculate the unemployment rate based of the data below and add it as new rows to the data table. I want to divide unemployed by labourforce based off the date and add each datapoint as a row.

Essentially, I am trying to go from this

| date | series_1 | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | labourforce | 13793 |
| 2021-02-01 | labourforce | 13812 |
| 2021-03-01 | labourforce | 13856 |
| 2021-01-01 | unemployed | 875 |
| 2021-02-01 | unemployed | 805 |
| 2021-03-01 | unemployed | 778 |

to this

| date | series_1 | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | labourforce | 13793 |
| 2021-02-01 | labourforce | 13812 |
| 2021-03-01 | labourforce | 13856 |
| 2021-01-01 | unemployed | 875 |
| 2021-02-01 | unemployed | 805 |
| 2021-03-01 | unemployed | 778 |
| 2021-01-01 | unemploymentrate | 6.3 |
| 2021-02-01 | unemploymentrate | 5.8 |
| 2021-03-01 | unemploymentrate | 5.6 |

Here is my code so far. I know the last line is wrong? Any suggestions or ideas are welcome!

```
longdata %>% 
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(series_1 = 'unemploymentrate',
  value = series_1$unemployed/series_1$labourforce))
```

Comment: it looks like you might benefit from more tidy data. If your data.frame would have the columns `date`, `labourforce` and `unemployed`, you could easily add another column called `unempleymentrate`. Once you did this you can still melt that data.frame with `reshape2::melt()` to bring it into the form you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fro each day, you can get the ratio of  `'unemployed'` by `'labourforce'` and add it as new rows to your original dataset.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(value = value[series_1 == 'unemployed']/value[series_1 == 'labourforce'] * 100, 
            series_1 = 'unemploymentrate') %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(series_1)

#   date          value series_1        
#  <chr>         <dbl> <chr>           
#1 2021-01-01 13793    labourforce     
#2 2021-02-01 13812    labourforce     
#3 2021-03-01 13856    labourforce     
#4 2021-01-01   875    unemployed      
#5 2021-02-01   805    unemployed      
#6 2021-03-01   778    unemployed      
#7 2021-01-01     6.34 unemploymentrate
#8 2021-02-01     5.83 unemploymentrate
#9 2021-03-01     5.61 unemploymentrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

 
  df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = series_1, values_from = value) %>% 
  mutate(unempolymentrate = round(unemployed*100/labourforce, 2)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "series_1", values_to = "value") %>%
    mutate(series_1 = factor(series_1, levels = c("labourforce", "unemployed", "unempolymentrate"))) %>% 
    arrange(series_1, date)

#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   date       series_1            value
#>   <chr>      <fct>               <dbl>
#> 1 2021-01-01 labourforce      13793   
#> 2 2021-02-01 labourforce      13812   
#> 3 2021-03-01 labourforce      13856   
#> 4 2021-01-01 unemployed         875   
#> 5 2021-02-01 unemployed         805   
#> 6 2021-03-01 unemployed         778   
#> 7 2021-01-01 unempolymentrate     6.34
#> 8 2021-02-01 unempolymentrate     5.83
#> 9 2021-03-01 unempolymentrate     5.61
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>
**data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-03-01", 
                              "2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-03-01"), series_1 = c("labourforce", 
                                                                                      "labourforce", "labourforce", "unemployed", "unemployed", "unemployed"
                              ), value = c(13793L, 13812L, 13856L, 875L, 805L, 778L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                           -6L))
```